# Remove inline style from sxa image tag in sitecore

Tags: sxa, presentation

I created rendering variant and inserted field like that:

[image]

and the image rendered as :

```
<img src="/master-site/-/media/Project/ADGEs/Master-Site/Register-Icon.svg" alt="" style="margin: 0px 0px;">
```

I need to remove inline style in the image tag, Is there a way to do that???

Answer (score 3):

`SetImageStyleParameters` from `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.RenderField` is responsible for that. It is used to add `HSpace` and `VSpace` from image properties. I don't know which version of SXA are you using but in the newest version, it should not add any additional margin when both `HSpace` and `VSpace` are 0.

If you don't need it, simply comment out this processor:

[image]